# How to parse xml as to extract fields for documentation?

Tags: xml, excel, bash, ksh

I am trying to do some research as to how to ease making documentation from already done Mappings in Informatica Powercenter, and the initial approach is difficult to me because of the amount of different options. The method followed here is to access each box in the mapping as many times as needed, copy the info into a word document, format it, and do this a few thousand times per week.

Right now I have what I think is a subpar idea for a solution: Export the Mapping to XML, parse said XML with a script (or program, I've tried a few times with excel, unseccesfully)  to something more easily copy-pasteable, and that way improve my life.

The XML looks like this (simplified to as few lines as possible to make an example, it might not be 100% valid but the original XML is, also, obviously Value assigned is something I put to not give relevance to whatever is the value, not that it's every single time that string):

```
Type 1 Document:

   <!DOCTYPE POWERMART SYSTEM "ValueAssigned">
<POWERMART CREATION_DATE="ValueAssigned" REPOSITORY_VERSION="ValueAssigned">
<REPOSITORY NAME="ValueAssigned" VERSION="ValueAssigned" CODEPAGE="ValueAssigned" DATABASETYPE="ValueAssigned">
<FOLDER NAME="ValueAssigned" GROUP="" OWNER="ValueAssigned" SHARED="ValueAssigned" DESCRIPTION="ValueAssigned" PERMISSIONS="ValueAssigned" UUID="ValueAssigned">
    <CONFIG DESCRIPTION ="ValueAssigned" ISDEFAULT ="YES" NAME ="ValueAssigned" VERSIONNUMBER ="ValueAssigned">
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Field1" VALUE =""/>
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Field2" VALUE ="NO"/>
    <WORKFLOW DESCRIPTION ="" ISENABLED ="ValueAssigned" ISRUNNABLESERVICE ="ValueAssigned" ISSERVICE ="ValueAssigned" ISVALID ="ValueAssigned" NAME ="ValueAssigned" REUSABLE_SCHEDULER ="ValueAssigned" SCHEDULERNAME ="ValueAssigned" SERVERNAME ="ValueAssigned" SERVER_DOMAINNAME ="ValueAssigned" SUSPEND_ON_ERROR ="ValueAssigned" TASKS_MUST_RUN_ON_SERVER ="ValueAssigned" VERSIONNUMBER ="ValueAssigned">
        <SCHEDULER DESCRIPTION ="" NAME ="SchedulerName" REUSABLE ="ValueAssigned" VERSIONNUMBER ="ValueAssigned">
            <SCHEDULEINFO SCHEDULETYPE ="ONDEMAND"/>
        </SCHEDULER>
        <TASK DESCRIPTION ="ValueAssigned" NAME ="Start" REUSABLE ="NO" TYPE ="Start" VERSIONNUMBER ="1"/>
        <SESSION DESCRIPTION ="ValueAssigned" ISVALID ="ValueAssigned" MAPPINGNAME ="ValueAssigned" NAME ="ValueAssigned" REUSABLE ="ValueAssigned" SORTORDER ="ValueAssigned" VERSIONNUMBER ="ValueAssigned">
            <SESSTRANSFORMATIONINST ISREPARTITIONPOINT ="ValueAssigned" PARTITIONTYPE ="ValueAssigned" PIPELINE ="ValueAssigned" SINSTANCENAME ="ValueAssigned" STAGE ="ValueAssigned" TRANSFORMATIONNAME ="ValueAssigned" TRANSFORMATIONTYPE ="Target Definition">
                <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="ValueAssigned" VALUE ="ValueAssigned"/>
                <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="ValueAssigned" VALUE ="ValueAssigned"/>
            </SESSTRANSFORMATIONINST>
```

So if we focus on one any tag, such as

```
<CONFIG DESCRIPTION ="Default session configuration object" ISDEFAULT ="YES" NAME ="default_session_config" VERSIONNUMBER ="29">
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Field1" VALUE =""/>
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Field2" VALUE ="NO"/>
```

We can see there is a Tag, CONFIG DESCRIPTION, followed but a couple attribute names. One of the options I'm thinking of is a bit naive, but if I were to get that to columns, in excel or similar, I could see a row with the root tag, and under that the different categories, and with that breakdown get to the point where I can see: Ok this is the tag, this is a column with all the values it has, I copy it to my word document and call it a day. Because in XML there are anywhere between 300 and 900 lines, and it's neither easy to see nor easy to use, because of the quotes, the constant tags, columns not being aligned because lines do not have the same length (so I can't use the column mode)...

I put the other type of document just in case it makes a more clear idea of how differen the info can be, and why I am not jumping straight into doing my own parser right away:

```
  <?xml version="ValueAssigned" encoding="ValueAssigned"?>
<!DOCTYPE POWERMART SYSTEM "ValueAssigned">
<POWERMART CREATION_DATE="ValueAssigned" REPOSITORY_VERSION="ValueAssigned">
<REPOSITORY NAME="ValueAssigned" VERSION="ValueAssigned" CODEPAGE="ValueAssigned" DATABASETYPE="ValueAssigned">
<FOLDER NAME="ValueAssigned" GROUP="ValueAssigned" OWNER="ValueAssigned" SHARED="ValueAssigned" DESCRIPTION="ValueAssigned" PERMISSIONS="ValueAssigned" UUID="ValueAssigned">
    <SOURCE BUSINESSNAME ="ValueAssigned" DATABASETYPE ="ValueAssigned" DBDNAME ="ValueAssigned" DESCRIPTION ="ValueAssigned" NAME ="ValueAssigned" OBJECTVERSION ="ValueAssigned" OWNERNAME ="ValueAssigned" VERSIONNUMBER ="ValueAssigned">
        <SOURCEFIELD BUSINESSNAME ="ValueAssigned" DATATYPE ="ValueAssigned" DESCRIPTION ="ValueAssigned" FIELDNUMBER ="ValueAssigned" FIELDPROPERTY ="ValueAssigned" FIELDTYPE ="ValueAssigned" HIDDEN ="ValueAssigned" KEYTYPE ="ValueAssigned" LENGTH ="ValueAssigned" LEVEL ="ValueAssigned" NAME ="ValueAssigned" NULLABLE ="ValueAssigned" OCCURS ="ValueAssigned" OFFSET ="ValueAssigned" PHYSICALLENGTH ="ValueAssigned" PHYSICALOFFSET ="ValueAssigned" PICTURETEXT ="ValueAssigned" PRECISION ="ValueAssigned" SCALE ="ValueAssigned" USAGE_FLAGS ="ValueAssigned"/>
<FOLDER NAME="ValueAssigned" GROUP="ValueAssigned" OWNER="ValueAssigned" SHARED="ValueAssigned" DESCRIPTION="ValueAssigned" PERMISSIONS="ValueAssigned" UUID="ValueAssigned">
    <SOURCE BUSINESSNAME ="ValueAssigned" CRCVALUE ="ValueAssigned" DATABASETYPE ="ValueAssigned" DBDNAME ="ValueAssigned" DESCRIPTION ="ValueAssigned" IBMCOMP ="ValueAssigned" NAME ="ValueAssigned" OBJECTVERSION ="ValueAssigned" OWNERNAME ="ValueAssigned" VERSIONNUMBER ="ValueAssigned">
        <FLATFILE CODEPAGE ="ValueAssigned" CONSECDELIMITERSASONE ="ValueAssigned" DELIMITED ="ValueAssigned" DELIMITERS ="ValueAssigned" ESCAPE_CHARACTER ="ValueAssigned" KEEPESCAPECHAR ="ValueAssigned" LINESEQUENTIAL ="ValueAssigned" MULTIDELIMITERSASAND ="ValueAssigned" NULLCHARTYPE ="ValueAssigned" NULL_CHARACTER ="ValueAssigned" PADBYTES ="ValueAssigned" QUOTE_CHARACTER ="ValueAssigned" REPEATABLE ="ValueAssigned" ROWDELIMITER ="ValueAssigned" SHIFTSENSITIVEDATA ="ValueAssigned" SKIPROWS ="ValueAssigned" STRIPTRAILINGBLANKS ="ValueAssigned"/>
        <SOURCEFIELD BUSINESSNAME ="ValueAssigned" DESCRIPTION ="ValueAssigned" FIELDNUMBER ="ValueAssigned" FIELDPROPERTY ="ValueAssigned" FIELDTYPE ="ValueAssigned" HIDDEN ="ValueAssigned" LENGTH ="ValueAssigned" LEVEL ="ValueAssigned" NAME ="ValueAssigned" OCCURS ="ValueAssigned" OFFSET ="ValueAssigned" PHYSICALLENGTH ="ValueAssigned" PHYSICALOFFSET ="ValueAssigned">
```

Comment: It is not very clear what you are trying to achieve. What specific data are you interested in extracting from the XML?
What do you want your info in your word document to look like?

Comment: I am sorry about the unclearness :S. I'll try explainin as if it was already solved it. I want to parse as much of the xml, and in such a clean way, that if I want to copy, say, Attributes from Session, I go to where it is and copy all of them (that's why I thought of excel). So I would like a process to make it easy to copy very different data from XMLs that look like what I wrote down, taking into account that this XML aren't always the same, with the same tags and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar in the past: transforming an xml file to a flat TXT file.
One of your problem is that XML is a nested format with list-like structure.

One thing that works is to flatten it this way:

```
<CONFIG DESCRIPTION ="Default session configuration object" ISDEFAULT ="YES" NAME ="default_session_config" VERSIONNUMBER ="29">
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Field1" VALUE =""/>
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Field2" VALUE ="NO"/>
</CONFIG>
```

becomes

```
CONFIG.DESCRIPTION = "Default session configuration object"
CONFIG.ISDEFAULT = ="YES"
CONFIG.NAME ="default_session_config"
CONFIG.VERSIONNUMBER ="29"
CONFIG.ATTRIBUTE[1].NAME="Field1"
CONFIG.ATTRIBUTE[1].VALUE =""
CONFIG.ATTRIBUTE[2].NAME="Field2"
CONFIG.ATTRIBUTE[2].VALUE ="NO"
```

basically having the Xpath = value format.
You can achieve that with python with the XML libraries or XSLT and an xsl template.

Comment: Thanks for the info! To get more ideas, would you mind why did you transform it to flat file? Like, what was the purpose behind. In my case that would be useful because if you then import it to excel and make the = the separator, it would be an improvement, so it's another idea to consider.

Comment: a flat file is more human readable than a a xml file and can be grep-ed more easily when working in a CLI environement.